# Trying to addPlugin chartjs-plugin-trendline to vue-chartjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs, trendline

No trendline is showing when integrating the chartjs-plugin-trendline plugin to vue-chart, tried to register it to charts default plugins but same, I checked all the issues tab in the library and tried registering Chart globally as what was suggested for someone who was trying to integrate it with react-chart but also didnt work, did it work with anyone?